# Doctrine & Symfony3 OneToOne relations, inverse side does not exist

Tags: php, database, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am looking for a clear explanation of how the relations work in Doctrine 2. I've been trying now for days to set up a OneToOne relation in Symfony3, and have read basically every thread and all the documentation, and i simply do not understand. The last few hours i've been bruteforcing my way into a OneToOne relation, with no luck.
Here's the problem i'm dealing with:

My user entity has a Team (which is itself an Entity)

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Gluckez\bballBundle\Entity\Team", 
mappedBy="Owner")
* @ORM\Column(name="team_id")
*/
private $team;
```

And My Team has an Owner, which refers to the User:

```
/**
 * @var User $Owner  
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", 
inversedBy="team_id")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="Owner_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $Owner;
```

Now in my User table, i can see the relations, which do point to the right team. but doctrine complains about the inverse side User#team, that does not exist (even though i'm pretty sure i've defined it?)
I've tried countless times to change the inversedby, mappedby, name, referencedcolumnName, as well as dropping and recreating the database and tables. updating the doctrine schema's. i'm out of idea's.
Not a single answer out there, nor the documentation of doctrine points me in the right direction. I realize that there's a lot of threads out there on this, but none of them are clear, or even answered.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this:

**Owner entity**

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Gluckez\bballBundle\Entity\Team", mappedBy="owner")
*/
private $team;
```

**Team entity**

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Application\Sonata\UserBundle\Entity\User", inversedBy="team")
 */
protected $owner;
```

As reference: [Association Mapping](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)

Comment: thank you for the quick reaction. What makes you think it should work like this? i'm just trying to understand. it's giving me the exact same error as before

Comment: Well, first, `@JoinColumn` isn't needed if you don't want to change the column name or the referenced column name. So it's best to let Symfony handle it. Second, you most likely made a mistake with `@Column`. I'm guessing that you wanted to point the referenced column id, which, first isn't needed again as Symfony will handle it, second isn't the good annotation.

Comment: oh ok, that's good to know. any idea as to how symfony handles this exactly?

Comment: Do you mean what it will generate?! it's all written in the doc, read the reference link in my answer... ;)

Comment: i've read it a few times already, and did so again, but all this really tells me is that it's getting the id's of the entities i'm creating a relation for. This doesn't explain why doctrine is saying that User#team does not exist, while it clearly does. it's just not persisting anything to the database when i'm updating my doctrine schema.

Comment: That problem was most likely because your relations was badly written. Did you correct with my code?! It should have solved your problem, no?

Comment: no, it didn't change anything... i've basically tried every possible value for inversedBy, but to no avail. i've tried adding it in the database manually too, but even that didn't work. not for 'team' nor for 'team_id'. owner_id shows up nicely though, and it's linked to the user. but the inverse side does nothing

Comment: It's odd... There is no mistakes in my answer... Have you tried to clean prod/dev cache then check again? Sometimes the cache get in the way

Comment: I believe that it works for you, but it doesn't for me for some reason. I cleared the cache, but that doesn't work either. i'm still getting the same problem, i've also dropped and recreated the entire database a few times, but that didn't work either.